# Explanation of LKM and procfs

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, proc

I am learning about the proc and loadable kernel module (LKM) for reading data from the kernel to the user space. [I asked for some info regarding procfs in another post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080920/how-to-transfer-the-kernel-data-to-user-data-using-procfs?noredirect=1#comment35277344_23080920)

Could someone please tell me what lkm and procfs are, and where I can write the code for lkm and proc (location in kernel source code)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't write code for an LKM inside kernel source (though it's possible, it's not recommended unless you're working on what will become a normally distributed module). You instead create your own directory and provide your code.

The functions you write to provide procfs interfaces is just code that is part of your LKM source.

http://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x769.html has a simple example using procfs, reproduced here:

```
/**
 *  procfs2.c -  create a "file" in /proc
 *
 */

#include <linux/module.h>   /* Specifically, a module */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* We're doing kernel work */
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>  /* Necessary because we use the proc fs */
#include <asm/uaccess.h>    /* for copy_from_user */

#define PROCFS_MAX_SIZE     1024
#define PROCFS_NAME         "buffer1k"

/**
 * This structure hold information about the /proc file
 *
 */
static struct proc_dir_entry *Our_Proc_File;

/**
 * The buffer used to store character for this module
 *
 */
static char procfs_buffer[PROCFS_MAX_SIZE];

/**
 * The size of the buffer
 *
 */
static unsigned long procfs_buffer_size = 0;

/** 
 * This function is called then the /proc file is read
 *
 */
int 
procfile_read(char *buffer,
          char **buffer_location,
          off_t offset, int buffer_length, int *eof, void *data)
{
    int ret;

    printk(KERN_INFO "procfile_read (/proc/%s) called\n", PROCFS_NAME);

    if (offset > 0) {
        /* we have finished to read, return 0 */
        ret  = 0;
    } else {
        /* fill the buffer, return the buffer size */
        memcpy(buffer, procfs_buffer, procfs_buffer_size);
        ret = procfs_buffer_size;
    }

    return ret;
}

/**
 * This function is called with the /proc file is written
 *
 */
int procfile_write(struct file *file, const char *buffer, unsigned long count,
           void *data)
{
    /* get buffer size */
    procfs_buffer_size = count;
    if (procfs_buffer_size > PROCFS_MAX_SIZE ) {
        procfs_buffer_size = PROCFS_MAX_SIZE;
    }

    /* write data to the buffer */
    if ( copy_from_user(procfs_buffer, buffer, procfs_buffer_size) ) {
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    return procfs_buffer_size;
}

/**
 *This function is called when the module is loaded
 *
 */
int init_module()
{
    /* create the /proc file */
    Our_Proc_File = create_proc_entry(PROCFS_NAME, 0644, NULL);

    if (Our_Proc_File == NULL) {
        remove_proc_entry(PROCFS_NAME, &proc_root);
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Error: Could not initialize /proc/%s\n",
            PROCFS_NAME);
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    Our_Proc_File->read_proc  = procfile_read;
    Our_Proc_File->write_proc = procfile_write;
    Our_Proc_File->owner      = THIS_MODULE;
    Our_Proc_File->mode       = S_IFREG | S_IRUGO;
    Our_Proc_File->uid    = 0;
    Our_Proc_File->gid    = 0;
    Our_Proc_File->size       = 37;

    printk(KERN_INFO "/proc/%s created\n", PROCFS_NAME);    
    return 0;   /* everything is ok */
}

/**
 *This function is called when the module is unloaded
 *
 */
void cleanup_module()
{
    remove_proc_entry(PROCFS_NAME, &proc_root);
    printk(KERN_INFO "/proc/%s removed\n", PROCFS_NAME);
}
```

The module initialization establishes a procfs entry with `create_proc_entry()`. The functions `procfile_write` and `procfile_read` are initialized to handle writes and reads on this entry. The module's `cleanup_module()` function, called when the module is unloaded, removes the procfs entry by calling `cleanup_module()`.

---

You'll find a tutorial for building kernel modules at http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-module.html. The summary of that is:

1) Ensure you have kernel source installed in /usr/src.

2) Create a makefile that looks like:

```
obj-m = procfs2.o
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

3) build the module with the command `make`
4) load the module into memory with the command `insmod procfs2.ko` (do this as the root user)

Not listed in the tutorial is: if your module has problems, expect to reboot. Crashes in kernel modules will often take down your system.

Comment: thank you very much . then I will add the above code in the /proc directory as procfs2.c. is it right ?? this procfs2.c acts as an interface between the user and kernel. is it right ??

Comment: I modified the kernel code and calculated the timestamp. later I want to write the timestamp from kernel to userspace. So could you please tell me how can I do that ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080920/how-to-transfer-kernel-data-to-user-data-using-procfs?noredirect=1#comment35277344_23080920

Comment: You don't add files in /proc... /proc is not really a file system, it's just an interface that looks like one. You load a module that creates a pseudo file in /proc, and client applications interact with your module by reading and writing that file.

Comment: sorry I am confused then where should I write and store the above code ? loading a module is nothing but mounting the above code to the /proc ??

Comment: Anywhere you want. It's not important where you put your sources. Putting it within the kernel source tree is probably not a good idea but nothing stops you. The location you choose is only important while you build your module -- and its importance is that it only matters to you, not to anything / anyone else.

Comment: could you please tell me the good or correct location for that ?? else I will create a directory called example and I will insert the above code in that as procfs2.c

Comment: last question : how to send the data from kernel to user as per the below link requirement : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080920/how-to-transfer-kernel-data-to-user-data-using-procfs?noredirect=1#comment35277344_23080920

Comment: Examine the `procfile_read()` function in the example I posted. That runs in the kernel, and it sends content back to the user via the `memcpy()` call; copying memory from the kernel to the user. The user is required to understand the format the kernel will be providing.

Comment: but how to send the timestamp calculated in kernel space i.e  __net_timestamp(skb); (this api will return the time at which the interrupt occurs and store it in a skb buffer)?? how to put the timestamp into the memcpy() ??

Comment: I don't know :) This page's question was not about that, it was about implementing a proofs entry in an LKM. The specifics of that are beyond this question.

Comment: if I copy the code and make the MAKEFILE and later if I give the make command from the console then it is showing as : make: nothing to be done for all. what could be the error ??

Comment: I can only guess, but my guess is that your indentation is not right. The make command is very particular about rule indentation within makefiles; the indentation on the lines following `all:` and `clean:` **must** be a tab; spaces will cause problems.

Comment: I copied the complete code from you only but it is showing that make: nothing to be done for all. I also check for the previous comment but it is fine then also i am getting the same error.